# Inserting values from cells in a string

Tags: string, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'd like to create some HTML and XML files with values coming from different cells and rows.

My idea is to put the HTML or XML template as a string in 1 cell and injecting values coming from different columns within the string. 
Something like:

```
<html>
<body>name: $A1<p></p><p>surname: $B1</p>
</html>
```

where $A1 and $B1 are the content of cells A1 and B1, so I can replicate it for each row.
Is this feasible in Google Sheets?

I've done similar things with `CONCATENATE` in the past but in this context where I need to pass 5 values in multiple places, it would be too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B1:B); "<html>
<body>name: "&A1:A&"<p></p><p>surname: "&B1:B&"</p>
</html>"; ))
```

[image: 0]

**[spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iyuYbSIcR_WjEEV95AXgHUoKUpvAPAryHDtqT0lS4ek/edit#gid=1480028316)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your formula return an error in my spreadsheet. Can you explain how it works? Why are you using an arrayformula and checking len of B1:B ?

Comment: @Gusepo arrayformula for continuity and checking B1:B with len for stopping the arrayformula at the end of dataset

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it very easily with

```
  ="<html>
  <body>name: "&B1&"<p></p><p>surname: "&B1&"</p>
  </html>"
```